# How do I connect Python to my Postgres Server?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have been having major trouble connecting my python shell to my postgres. I am doing this on windows. I have downloaded psycopg2 and everything for this to process, however it still is not working.

```
    import psycopg2
    conn=psycopg2.connect("dbname = 'test' user ='postgres' host ='localhost' password = 'mypassword'")
```

It gives me an error telling me that the database "test" does not exist, however it does! If you guys have any advice at all on what I should test out, that would be amazing. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using either “dbname=test ...” or dbname=‘test’, ... as suggested by [their documentation here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html)?

Comment: Yes, that works as well to connect to a database. The only database that I am able to connect to is postgres. I can not get into any of the ones that I have created

Comment: I solved it. It was only looking for the databases in my postgresSQL 9.5 version, not my postgresSQL version 10. Would you know how to connect it to my postgresSQL version 10 instead?

Comment: You can set the Postgres version you want to execute as an environment variable similar to [this](https://www.enterprisedb.com/fr/docs/en/9.3/instguide/Postgres_Plus_Advanced_Server_Installation_Guide.1.32.html), but I’d strongly recommend sticking with one version of postgres. If you really need to have both versions running for different apps, then I’d put them in separate docker containers.

Answer (score 0):

You can layout connection parameters as a string and pass it to the connect() function as like:

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres password=postgres")

Or you can use a list of keyword arguments like

conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost",database="test", user="postgres", password="postgres")

If its still fails then you should check on PostgreSQL side. You should try to connect the db in question using command line and see if error re appears or not. if it appears then something is missing on DB server side.